# Data Binding with WPF and MVVM/Model-View-ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm having difficulty correctly Data Binding my models in the view.  I have a MainWindowViewModel which contains a list of AlbumViewModels.  Each AlbumViewModel holds an AlbumModel.  So I have multiple albums and I need to display information in an ObservableCollection in the AlbumModel.  I have two ListBoxes.  ListBox1 holds the list of AlbumViewModels that are in my MainWindowViewModel.  My second ListBox I want to display the ObservableCollection from the current selected item from the AlbumViewModel.AlbumModel.  How can I do this?  I've tried binding the DataContext of ListBox2 to the ListBox1 element, along with SelectedItem as the path but that returns 'AlbumViewModel'.  Is there anyway to bind ItemsSource of a ListBox to the binding of the DataContext, but in this case binding it to `[DataContext].AlbumModel.ObservableCollection` or something?

I apologise if it sounds rather complicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact, that when you bind to a collection, WPF wraps collection to  [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx). And this guy has [CurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.currentitem.aspx).. Bea had good article: [How can I sync selection of two data bound ListBoxes?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=12) and Dr.WPF is amazing (as usual): [ItemsControl: 'C' is for Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/05/itemscontrol-c-is-for-collection/#CollectionView).

Comment: Ah ok, that's interesting.  Thanks.  It's worked but now I'm trying to figure out how to display my Model.  Obviously I don't want the View to have access to the Model, so how can I create a DateTemplate for it without exposing the Model?

edit: Nevermind. it's working.  I just created a DataTemplate with a key rather than a DataType :) Thanks muchly!